# request SQL in 2 table

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, inner-join

I am looking to consolidate 2 SQL queries for the optimization, here are my 2 queries.

```
SELECT name, mess, image, date
FROM post_normal
WHERE name = flarize
ORDER BY date DESC

SELECT name, mess, image, name_second, image_second, quote, date
FROM post_special
WHERE name = flarize
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Thank you, I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: What does "consolidate" mean?  Sample data and desired results would help -- as would an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you nedd  both  the result is the same table  you could use a UNION

```
    SELECT name, mess, image, null, null, null, date 
    FROM post_normal 
    WHERE name = flarize 

    UNION 

    SELECT name, mess, image, name_second, image_second, quote, date 
    FROM post_special 
    WHERE name = flarize 
    ODER BY date DESC
```

if you need on a single row you can use  JOIN

```
   SELECT a.name, a.mess, a.image, a.date
        , b.name, b.mess, b.image, b.name_second, b.image_second, b.quote, b.date 
    FROM post_normal a 
    LEFT  JOIN post_special b on a.name = b.name a.name = 'flariz'
```